# PHP cURL Error 60 - Traditional Solutions Not Working

Tags: php, curl

Getting the classic error:

```
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Relevant specs:

- Windows 10 x64
- PHP 7.4.6

I've tried:

- Setting `curl.cainfo` and `openssl.cafile` to a freshly-downloaded [cacert.pem](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html)
- Generating my own certificates and adding them to the Windows certificate store

Setting my client to ignore verification is not an option. This needs to work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use any WAMP, XAMP servers? If so you need to make sure that you are editing the right php.ini file. Make sure to have the path correctly with the "/" in windows.

curl.cainfo = "D:/WAMP64/bin/php/php7.4.0/extras/ssl/cacert.pem"

Comment: No, I have manually installed and configured Apache and PHP instances. The Apache service was installed by command line with a specific config location, and I created the PHP module configuration by hand. Versioning is largely controlled by environment variable, but I've also rebooted numerous times since and removed prior versions, so this is the only php.ini file it could use.